# How to return a potential NULL in SQL while performing a comparison on the potentially null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

Developing a query that will return information about an item stored across 4 tables. When all the fields have values my query works fine, however some of the data has null fields (which I can't change) that I need to perform my comparison on. When these show up, the row doesn't show up in the query results, even if all the other fields have values.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  select [Item_NO], [Color_Name], [size_code], [style_code], [PERM_UNIT_PRICE]
  FROM [USICOAL].[dbo].[ITEM], [USICOAL].[dbo].[COLOR], [USICOAL].[dbo].[SIZE], [USICOAL].[dbo].[STYLE]
  where [ITEM_NO] in ('191202002944', '191202003026')
  AND [USICOAL].[dbo].[ITEM].[COLOR_ID] = [USICOAL].[dbo].[COLOR].[COLOR_ID]
  AND [USICOAL].[dbo].[ITEM].[SIZE_ID] = [USICOAL].[dbo].[SIZE].[SIZE_ID]
  AND [USICOAL].[dbo].[ITEM].[STYLE_ID] = [USICOAL].[dbo].[STYLE].[STYLE_ID]
```

For these 2 items numbers, the Size_ID field is null. How can I get the results to reflect this null?

Comment: Don't use old style joins.

Comment: To start, you need to use ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins My guess is that is the issue. As posted every single one of your joins is an inner join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we do LEFT JOIN with old syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768524/how-do-we-do-left-join-with-old-syntax)

Comment: Thanks, Old habits die hard. been a while since I touched SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   [Item_NO]
  ,[Color_Name]
  ,[size_code]
  ,[style_code]
  ,[PERM_UNIT_PRICE]
FROM 
  [USICOAL].[dbo].[ITEM] i
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  [USICOAL].[dbo].[COLOR] c
  ON c.[COLOR_ID] = i.[COLOR_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  [USICOAL].[dbo].[SIZE] s
  ON s.[SIZE_ID] = i.[SIZE_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  [USICOAL].[dbo].[STYLE] t
  ON t.[STYLE_ID] = i.[STYLE_ID]
WHERE
  [ITEM_NO] in ('191202002944', '191202003026')
```